# Leakage when using Task.Factory.FromAsync

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, mono

I’ve been working with Task.Factory.FromAsync() methods and have been experiencing severe memory leakage. I’ve used the profiler and it shows that a lot of objects just seem to be hanging around after use:

```
    Heap shot 140 at 98.591 secs: size: 220177584, object count: 2803125, class count: 98, roots: 666
         Bytes      Count  Average Class name
      25049168     142325      175 System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Int32> (bytes: +398816, count: +2266)
            1 root references (1 pinning)
            142324 references from: System.Threading.Tasks.Task
            142305 references from: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<System.Int32>
            98309 references from: task_test.Task3Test.<Run>c__AnonStorey1
      25049024     142324      176 System.Threading.Tasks.Task (bytes: +398816, count: +2266)
            142304 references from: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskContinuation
      17078880     142324      120 System.Action<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Int32>> (bytes: +271920, count: +2266)
            142324 references from: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskActionInvoker.ActionTaskInvoke<System.Int32>
      17076600     142305      120 System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.MonoMethodMessage (bytes: +271680, count: +2264)
            1 root references (1 pinning)
            142304 references from: System.MonoAsyncCall
      17076584     142305      119 System.AsyncCallback (bytes: +271920, count: +2266)
            1 root references (1 pinning)
            142304 references from: System.MonoAsyncCall
      17076584     142305      119 System.Func<System.Int32> (bytes: +271920, count: +2266)
            1 root references (1 pinning)
            142305 references from: System.Func<System.IAsyncResult,System.Int32>
            142304 references from: System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult
            1 references from: System.Func<System.AsyncCallback,System.Object,System.IAsyncResult>
      17076584     142305      119 System.Func<System.IAsyncResult,System.Int32> (bytes: +271920, count: +2266)
            1 root references (1 pinning)
            142305 references from: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory.<FromAsyncBeginEnd>c__AnonStorey3A<System.Int32>
      17076480     142304      120 System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult (bytes: +271800, count: +2265)
            98461 references from: System.Object[]
```

I’m trying to work out what type of things may/may not be occurring that prevent the gc from recognizing the object is no longer in use. FromAsync returns a Task object which is obtained from TaskCompletionSource which has a class variable “source” that holds the value of the Task it in turn gets from the new Task invocation.

Here's the test case. It also includes a case using StartNew() where there is no explosion in memory use. The initial Test3Task below did not use the ContinueWith but to see if it was something we weren't cleaning up we put it in (to no effect). [And no, the listening variable used below is redundant - there were plans to make the test more intelligent but a do forever was just as good.]

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace task_test
{
    class MainClass
    {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                    // Test3 - Leaky
                    var t = new Task3Test();

                    // Test4 - Doesn't leak
                    // var t = new Task4Test();

                    t.Run();

            }
    }

    public class BaseTask
    {
            public int GetRandomInt(int top)
            {
                    Random random = new Random();

                    return random.Next(1,top);
            }
    }

    public class FibArgs
    {
            public byte[] data;
            public int n;
    }

    public class Fib
    {
            public int Calculate(FibArgs args)
            {
                    int n = args.n;

                    int a = 0;
                    int b = 1;
                    // In N steps compute Fibonacci sequence iteratively.
                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    {
                            int temp = a;
                            a = b;
                            b = temp + b;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("ThreadId: {2}, fib({0}) = {1}", n, a, Thread.CurrentThread.GetHashCode());
                    return a;
            }
    }

    public class Task3Test : BaseTask
    {
            public void Run()
            {
                    bool listening = true;
                    long i = 0;
                    while (listening)
                    {
                            i++;

                            Func<int> fun = () => {
                                    int n = GetRandomInt(100);
                                    Fib f = new Fib();
                                    FibArgs args = new FibArgs();
                                    args.n = n;

                                    return f.Calculate(args);
                            };

                            var t = Task<int>.Factory.FromAsync(fun.BeginInvoke, fun.EndInvoke, null);
                            t.ContinueWith( x => { 
                                                    if (x.IsCompleted) {
                                                            x.Dispose();
                                                            x = null;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    );
                    }
            }
    }

    public class Task4Test : BaseTask
    {
            public void Run()
            {
                    bool listening = true;
                    long i = 0;
                    while (listening)
                    {
                            int n = GetRandomInt(100);
                            Fib f = new Fib();
                            FibArgs args = new FibArgs();
                            args.n = n;

                            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => f.Calculate(args), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
                                    .ContinueWith(x => {
                                            if(x.IsFaulted)
                                            { 
                                                    Console.WriteLine("OOPS, error!!!");
                                                    x.Exception.Handle(_ => true); //just an example, you'll want to handle properly

                                            }
                                            else if(x.IsCompleted)
                                            {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Cleaning up task {0}", x.Id);
                                                    x.Dispose();
                                            }
                                    }
                            );
                    }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm running this with SGen on Darwin/x86 and memory usage is very stable after a few minutes.  With Boehm, however, it balloons up quite quickly.  Which GC are you using, on which platform?

Comment: My coworker and I tested something similar on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit and saw similar behavior with GCs.

Comment: Running with both. Used sgen to get heapshots and it blows through memory in no time flat.

Comment: Further bizarre symptoms. I run this test case on s390x and I see the normal swelling of memory. However, if I either (a) remove the WriteLine from the Calculate method, (b) redirect stdout or (c) pipe stdout, then I don't see the problem at all! I verified that the program is still running in these cases and that we're churning out tasks. This is using boehm. s390x seems to have a problem running this app with sgen. It appears that the problem may be due to OoM.

Comment: Reran s390x with sgen and profiler. Very different results if for the Console.WriteLine included/excluded. The excluded version is fairly stable - not completely leak free by the look of it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that you're creating tasks more quickly than they finish, so they queue up.

Comment: We see this with our http listener wrapper when we're hitting it a few times per second.

Comment: Are you sure that your tasks finish quickly enough for them not to queue up?  Can you modify your test case so that it demonstrates the problem you're actually seeing?

Comment: I can now definitely confirm that this specific test case leaks memory because of tasks queuing up.

Comment: We saw a very steady rise in memory usage when using Task.FromAsync in our code to process http requests (basically a REST server).  When using Task.StartNew, it does not happen.  Our current strategy is to remove all calls to Task.FromAsync().  In our test scenarios for our production code, we were not processing many requests per second.